# Excited or the excitement

Tags: word-choice

Do you use "feel excitement" instead of "feel excited"?

1. "I don't feel excited when I have to give a presentation."
2. "I don't feel excitement when I have to give a presentation."
   Should I use "the" before "excitement"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean. "I don't feel excited" means that you yourself don't feel excited, that you don't feel excitement coming from yourself. "I don't feel excitement" can mean that, but it also can mean that you don't feel others' excitement, that you don't feel excitement coming from others, possibly suggesting that you feel others are not excited, are less than enthused or maybe even crestfallen, when you have to give a presentation. "I don't feel excited" does not express that possibility.

Comment: Should I use "the" before excitement? I have seen it in other examples but I am not sure I should use it in my sentence.